# Is this one [Rotation] too many?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Recently encountered the [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation) tag on a question in the Close Votes queue and, as it seems to serve no clear purpose, it appears to be a ripe candidate for burnination.

This tag has just over 10,000 questions, so that might be a good reason to leave it alone, but I thought I would ask.

Looking at the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7508700) for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

There is no usage guidance in the tag wiki, but it does refer to several forms of rotation (axial, point, screen).

From a quick sample of the questions, they include:

- [Rotating an image around a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382124/how-to-rotate-a-view-using-panresponder-in-react-native)
- [Rotating an image around an axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379702/three-js-rotation-on-axix-with-wrl-object)
- [Rotating a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343069/when-i-rotate-the-screen-the-fragment-is-destroyed-and-returned-to-activity-wh)
- [Rotating a display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280560/rpi4-rotating-x-org-window-with-chromium)
- [Quaternions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118786/is-there-a-perl-way-of-doing-quaternion-euler-angles-conversion)
- [Rotating a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009941/daily-coding-problem-58-searching-a-sorted-list-that-has-been-rotated)
- [Rotating text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009941/daily-coding-problem-58-searching-a-sorted-list-that-has-been-rotated)
- [Rotating in a red-black tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568023/how-to-rotate-in-red-black-tree/50571112#50571112)
- [Rotating a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455274/robotc-sonar-sensor-array)
- [Rotating logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317724/fluentd-not-honoring-log-rotation)

Fine, you might say, they <del>all</del> mostly contain some sort of matrix/mathematical rotation.

If they are, mostly, sufficiently similar to be in one tag, then what would the purpose be of the generic tags:
[image-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-rotation)
[screen-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-rotation)
[log-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-rotation)
[auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation)
[autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate)
[text-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-rotation)
[tree-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-rotation)
[key-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-rotation)
[rotateanimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotateanimation)

as well as a few mathematical ones and a couple of tool-specific tags

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, obviously there's a lot of good, solid questions in there.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

It doesn't appear to be that helpful. Although a lot of its posts are around image rotation, < 20% of the questions tagged [image-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-rotation) are also tagged with [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation), so it might make it harder to search related questions.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Rotation does generally apply to the dictionary definitions of rotation, but the practical usage is not the same throughout.

I'm prepared to accept that the consensus might be that it's too big, doesn't really do any harm, etc. but [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation) does seem to mean very different things to different people, when better, more-specific (if inconsistently named) tags exist.

Comment: Good choice of target.

Comment: I would think that the most natural use for the term rotation in computer science is rotating a binary value. There are often rotate instructions in assembler. I can't find any suitable tag for that, though.

Comment: @Lundin Cannot find a tag, either. But there are [69 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Brotation%5D+%5Bbit-manipulation%5D&mixed=1) with tags [rotation] and [bit-manipulation], so definitely it's a thing. We would need to create a new tag for that.

Comment: @janw `bit-rotation` seems like a good name for such a tag.

Comment: Yes, more specific tags would be great, but it's a lot of work and afterwards one should make sure, that people using rotation get a message telling them to choose a more specific rotation and maybe an offer of choices.

Comment: Regarding image-rotation, it already implies rotation and is additionally much more specific. Would a search for rotation also include image-rotation results? If yes, I would just remove rotation from all questions also tagged image-rotation.

Comment: @Trilarion Only 112 (~ 1%) of the images with [tag:rotation] also have [tag:image-rotation] so just removing [tag:rotation] from those won't have a major impact. The others just tagged [tag:image-rotation] do not show up in a search for [tag:rotation]

Comment: And congratulations for the great word play, it's important in te process of judging a tag

Comment: @AntoinePelletier There are some standards that must be maintained.

Comment: @Trilarion why tho? Is there any benefit on having [rotation-*] or [rotation]?

Comment: @Braiam I mostly meant that people may not guess more specific tag names right in a search. But it's fine. Just tried to add tags and they display all variants where rotation is part of when typing it in.

Comment: Is there no tag for `qubit-rotation`?  That was my first thought on the subject line...

Comment: @DanielWiddis I expect using qubit-spin :D

Comment: I wonder whether the tag could be split into multiple, like (just an idea): `transformation-rotation` (or `rotation-transformation`) `physical-rotation` (rotating hardware), `tree-rotation` (`graph-rotation`?) In any case, a *clear description of the tag* is most important (maybe even more important than the actual name), but still: The user has to find what he/she is looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this should go.

This now has the following tag usage guidance:

> A rotation is a circular movement of an object around a center (or point) of rotation. On a mobile device, it indicates the change of orientation.

That's two uses of it right there, making this tag ambiguous.

one point I disagree with you on: I'm not so convinced that this is even always on-topic. There are plenty of valid interpretations of this tag that are not on topic. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068359/is-there-a-way-in-topology-to-prove-that-any-mapping-from-r3-to-so3-always-ha) an example of a question that fits the tag and the tag description perfectly well and yet is about math, not programming. (For those that aren't aware, SO(3) is the [3D rotation group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group)). On the plus side, the fact that the tag isn't attracting all *that* many OT questions will simplify burnination.