# Synonym/Re-tag request for [auto-rotation] and [autorotate]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Looking into rotation questions for the recent [burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400239/is-this-one-rotation-too-many) for [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation), I commented that there were two tags, [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) and [auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) which have 407 and 124 questions respectively.

Looking at the questions for both, they appear to be identical in usage, simply relating to screen auto-rotation in mobile devices. Neither has a tag Wiki entry.

There is one obviously related tag, [shouldautorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shouldautorotate) but that appears to relate to a specific function.

Looking at these questions, I also noticed that they have a variety of tags related to 'orientation' - in fact there are 11 tags regarding 'orientation', that appear very simular in nature, but that can wait for another meta post.

I think at the very least one of [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) and [auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) should be made a synonym of the other, but I do not have the score in either tag to suggest this. My suggestion would be make [auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) the primary tag and [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) the synonym, as most of the other tags with **rotation** are generic, descriptive tags, but most of the tags with **rotate** are specific to a function or package.

I'm not sure that much would be gained from re-tagging, instead of creating a synonym, especially as the path of least resistance would be to retag them all to [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) which seems to be the wrong answer, but I have tagged that on this question as a possible outcome.

Answer (score 8):

Hot take: Retag both to [screen-orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-orientation). It has ~1500 questions, and the short wiki says this:

> Detects whether the screen is in portrait orientation (height > width) or landscape orientation (width > height), and switches between the two. This term is especially used in mobile devices, where applications are notified when the user rotates the device.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but there are many `orientation` tags. I think `device-orientation`, `screen-orientation`, `orientation-changes`, `interface-orientation`, `android-orientation`, `uiscreenorientation`, `uiimageorientation`, `uideviceorientation` need to be disambiguated before retagging more questions to one of them.

Answer (score 6):

I checked the two tags, and it looks like they were being used interchangeably. I created the following synonym:

[auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) (× 124) → [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) (× 407)

As for what the other answer mentions, it looks like that'll require some disambiguation efforts before being merged. Let's wait for a few more days to see if there's any additional support for/against merging [autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) with [screen-orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-orientation) and then decide.

Comment: Thanks Bhargav. Is there any value posting a separate question about the `orientation` tags and how to disambiguate?

Comment: Any discussion on disambiguating tags is always valuable to us. (That said, personally I feel that most of the tags that you mentioned in the other comment _seem_ fine. `orientation-changes` is the only one which seems to be bad)