# Retag [text-rotating] to [text-rotation]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

My last request resulting from my [burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400239/is-this-one-rotation-too-many) of [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation), honest...

As I mentioned in that request, there are many tags which end in `-rotation`. There is one tag that ends in `-rotating` and that is [text-rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-rotating) which contains 39 questions.

Can we retag [text-rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-rotating) to [text-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-rotation) to aid in its discovery, if people are looking for tags containing `rotation`? If a burnination of [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rotation) takes place, it may result in questions being retagged to this tag, and it would seem better to rename it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can.

And now, we have.